# how to make a flat list from a list that consist of string,tuple and list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to flatten a list that consist of integer, tuple and a list. My list is something like:

> **List = [1,(45,54),[100,200]]**

and I want to new list like this:

> NW = [1,45,54,100,200]

Is there anyway to do this? I know how to flatten a list of lists or list of tuples but I couldnt figure that out how to do it all together. Is there anyway to do this without importing itertools? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without imports:

```
new_list = []
for el in List:
    if isinstance(el, list) or isinstance(el, tuple):
        new_list.extend([*el])
    else:
        new_list.append(el)
```

It works by conditioning on the type of the elements. Are there other types that might be present in the original list?

Comment: Does it work for strings also if I use isinstance for string?

Comment: you can convert a string to a list with the list() function. eg list('hello') == ['h', 'e', 'l','l','o']

Comment: Add  `or isinstance(el, range)` if your input includes `range()` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable) to test for iterable elements, and feed a generator comprehension to [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from collections import Iterable
from itertools import chain

L = [1,(45,54),[100,200]]

res = list(chain.from_iterable([i] if not isinstance(i, Iterable) else i for i in L))

[1, 45, 54, 100, 200]
```

Comment: The one solution that worked for me, when the list includes a `range()` object. Note you may need to update the `from collections import ...` to `from collections.abc import ...`.

Comment: Also, if the list is comprised of a single integer, some special handling is needed. So, I put that code in a function that checks the argument's type. If arg `x` is an `int`, then return `[x]`.